# How to zip image files in ionic 3

Tags: angular, soap, ionic3

I am developing my app using ionic 3. Can anyone tell me **how to zip the files** and how to send those files Using SOAP call.

I have check with the following link,

```
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/zip/
```

Here we can able to unzip the file.

Suggest me how to zip the file..

**Anyone help will be appreciated!!!**

Comment: Take a look at this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26191771/download-and-zip-files-client-side and this lib https://stuk.github.io/jszip/

Comment: I want to know how to achieve this using ionic 3????

Comment: Ionic is a javascript app. So you can do anything in Ionic with a javascript app. Do some research using this as entry point.

Comment: ok thanks. Ionic 3 is a angular latest version application. so there no any documents to achieve.Do u know how to do this using ionic 3 and angular 4?